# How to test alert invoked in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to test alert invoke when the counter from redux store reach point of 20. I listen the counter value from `useEffect` hook and then invoke an alert. Here I attach the part of App component and my test case.

App component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { configureStore, createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AnyAction, combineReducers, Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const increment = createAction<number>('increment');
export const decrement = createAction<number>('decrement');

export const counter = (state = 0, action: AnyAction) =>
  increment.match(action)
    ? state + action.payload
    : decrement.match(action)
    ? state - action.payload
    : state;

const root = combineReducers({ counter });

const timer = ({
  dispatch,
  getState,
}: {
  dispatch: Dispatch;
  getState: any;
}) => {
  setInterval(() => dispatch(increment(1)), 1000);

  return (next: Dispatch) => (action: AnyAction) => {
    const store = getState();
    if (store.counter < 0) {
      next(decrement(1));
    } else if (store.counter < 21 || !increment.match(action)) {
      next(action);
    }
  };
};

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: root,
  middleware: [timer],
});

/* const handleStateChange = () => {
  const state = store.getState();
  if (state.counter === 20) {
    alert('Your counter reached the value 20!');
  }
}

store.subscribe(handleStateChange) */

const App = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState<number>(1);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const counter = useSelector((state: Record<string, number>) => state.counter);

  const handleChange = (value: string) => {
    const convertedValue = Number(value);
    setStep(convertedValue);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 20) {
      alert('Your counter reached the value 20!')
    }
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeStamp = new Date();
    console.log('Did Mount: ', timeStamp);

    return () => console.log('Did Unmount ', new Date());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement(step))}>-</button>
      {counter}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(step))}>+</button>
      <div>
        Step equal to:
        <select
          value={step}
          onChange={(value) => handleChange(value.target.value)}
        >
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Test suite:

```js
it('Should trigger alert when reach 20', () => {
    const previousState = 19;
    const store = mockStore(previousState);
    const alert = jest.spyOn(window, 'alert').mockImplementation();
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );

    userEvent.click(screen.getByText('+'));
    expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**UPD:** Added full code of app component for clear understanding.

Comment: What's the point of the `setTimeout` and then immediately clearing it? From what I see the `alert` will never fire since the timeout to trigger it is immediately cancelled. Other than this, what is the issue you are asking for help with? Or is *that* your question, you want to know why this implementation isn't working, and you are trying to test it, and that is failing because `window.alert` is never called? Is there something in the UI code that updates the `count` state that the test is triggering so there's even a chance for the alert to be triggered?

Comment: @DrewReese, the counter works by it self in redux middleware. Also there are two buttons "+" and "-" - increment and decrement accordinaly. When the counter reach value of 20, the `alert` func is fired. If I remove the `timeout`, then UI show me 19, counter in redux would be 20 and `alert` will fired, but we need to wait UI render correct value, that's why I use `timeout`. And `alert` works. I already read the documentation of react-testing-library, jest and topics on stackoverflow, but I did not find a hint or solution.

Comment: Ok, I see, the store is auto-incrementing the `counter` state. I still don't see the purpose of the timeout in the UI code though, the `useSelector` hook should pick up the current `counter` state value and you should be able to reference that current value in the `useEffect` hook. And for the reason I explained in my first comment, the `clearTimeout(timer)` immediately clears the timeout before it can expire. This all seems like a code smell to me. `clearTimeout` is also a void return, you may want to ***not*** return it from the hook in case it's interpreted as a cleanup function.

Comment: I removed the `timeout` because find out that the `alert` works correctly, just stops all processes until you click "ok". Anyway, the test case doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, `window.alert` blocks the main thread, which is less than ideal just about anywhere you are trying to implement a UI a user interacts with. Mocking the `window.alert` implementation with code that doesn't block the main thread could possibly work. Or you could use something else entirely, anything other than `alert` would likely be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work with `waitFor`

```
it('Should trigger alert when reach 20', async () => {
  const previousState = 19;
  const store = mockStore(previousState);
  const alert = jest.spyOn(window, 'alert').mockImplementation();
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  userEvent.click(screen.getByText('+'));
  await waitFor(()=>{
    expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: thx, but not in my case